# Basic Authentication with htaccess but without password file

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, password

Can I use htaccess to restrict access to my site and specify the username/password within the .htaccess, so I don't have to worry about password files?

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely use .htaccess to restrict access, but I don't know of any way to avoid creating an equivalent .htpasswd file if you want to control access via users and passwords, rather than whitelisted IP addresses or similar.

Now, you *can* create any number of .htpasswd files; so if you wanted a specific one for a specific directory, that would be easy to set up by creating the .htpasswd file using:

```
htpasswd /usr/local/etc/apache/.your_htpasswd_filename_here username_here
```

then specifying it using the "AuthUserFile" directive in your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

It would not be *that* wise to have the users and passwords inside the .htaccess file (or the apache-config itself) for min. two main reasons.

See, the .htaccess lies *inside* a directory of your website. The password file should **never** lie there, because everyone could then download it and has a complete list of valid usernames. And can brute force their passwords offline.

Another reason could be that you could have a large number of users/groups for a BASIC auth protected website. You do not want to mix server config and authentication database.

Comment: Apache should never let anyone download the .htaccess file, or you have problems. Normal httpd.conf has a directory match for all .htaccess files with deny all. How easy is it to get the .htaccess file from outside the machine?

If you only need one user/password for a given path, it won't be hard to maintain. 

If the username is not a shell account to the machine then the web data it protects is the only risk if the .htaccess file is compromised.